# Sidekiq execute job after the other job is done

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

How can I manage to execute job after the first job that has executed is done in sidekiq. For example:
I triggered the first job for this morning

```
GoodWorker.perform_async(params) #=> JID-eetc
```

while it is still in progress I've executed again a job in the same worker dynamically

```
GoodWorker.perform_ascyn(params) #=> JID-eetc2
```

and etc.
What's going on now is Sidekiq processing the jobs all of the time,
is there a way performing the job one at a time?

Comment: I know sidekiq is built for parallel execution but is there an other way to process queue sequentially?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: You can use a mutex to guarantee that only one instance of a worker is executing at a time. If you're running on a cluster, you'll need to use Redis or some other medium to maintain the mutex. Otherwise, you might try putting these jobs in their own queue, and firing up a separate instance of Sidekiq that only monitors that queue, with a concurrency of one.

Comment: Can you suggest other gem that can answer my problem? Thanks.

Comment: @IsmaelEri You mean, something to use instead of Sidekiq, or something that can enable this feature in Sidekiq?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not setup Sidekiq to only have one thread? Then only one job will be executed at a time.